# Record sounds on web browser

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to build a site that records sounds. The site would have a meter that calculates the loudness of the sound. I have made a lot of research but I'm not able to find any solution on HTML5 that is supported in all browsers. Could you please help me if you know any stable service, API or library that can help me to solve this issue other than soundcloud :)

Thanks

Comment: Try this, it seems that it works and that's what you're looking for (http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/][http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/]

Comment: These solutions are not supported on IE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `navigator.getUserMedia()` API outlined in the HTML5 docs is the most effective way of gathering raw audio input from a user's microphone. It is very extendable, and is mostly cross-browser. [Here is a good resource on it.](https://nusofthq.com/blog/recording-mp3-using-only-html5-and-javascript-recordmp3-js/)

If you're  willing to go this route, there is also a library someone wrote for it that facilitates the easy capturing of that data, and its called Recorderjs. I also recommend it strongly, and its written MIT license. It's the go-to for many people in these types of projects. https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs

`getUserMedia` is just *too* native to ignore, and I'd go for it, even more than a plugin solution.

**Edit:** You mentioned you needed Internet Explorer support.  If you want to find a way to do this, the fallback would be a mix of Flash and JavaScript, as shown in this software library, which also supports Internet Explorer. It's a great method implementing audio recording, and maybe that works for you?

github.com/jwagener/recorder.js

Comment: I want to support IE, and all these library are not supported IE

Comment: Media Cpature and Streams and the Web Audio API are slated for the next Internet Explorer release, but sorry, for the time being, there is no current support of it. For the meanwhile, if you really want to support IE you are left with plugins, such as Java and Flash. Internet Explorer is still kind of backwards in that way. Source: http://developers.slashdot.org/story/14/05/29/1429254/next-ie-version-will-feature-web-audio-media-capture-es6-promises-and-http2 @MouhamadKawas

Comment: Sorry, hope it helped :) If you want to find a way to do this, the fallback would be a mix of Flash and JavaScript, as shown in this software library, which also supports Internet Explorer. https://github.com/jwagener/recorder.js/ It's a great method implementing audio recording, and maybe that works for you? @MouhamadKawas